# Is there a reference book for the duality between the genus of function fields and the discriminant of number fields?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Bjorn Poonen mentions in his "Lectures on rational points on curves" the analogy between the genus of a function field and the discriminant of number fields. I'm looking for a reference book for this statement.

Comment: Neukirch, Algebraic Number Theory, is a suitable reference.

Comment: Also, *Basic Number Theory* by Weil.

Comment: <i>Fourier Analysis on Number Fields</i>, by Ramakrishnan and Valenza covers this and is (in my opinion) somewhat easier than the two references suggested above.

Comment: Can you tell me the exact passage..

Comment: You might also consult van der Geer and Schoof's paper on the Theta divisor of a number field. You can find it on Schoof's webpage.

Comment: The genus of a number field is due to Weil and contained in Chapter III of Neukirch.